# Xiaomi MI PAD is not listed on supported devices in play store console

Tags: android

I've built my app, and uploaded onto google play store.

The developers console shows the list that support my app's manifest condition. I have been testing with my xiaomi pad, however, it is not listed on supported devices.

Here is AndroidMenifest.xml's snippet

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

And Xiaomi pad screen configuration from code is

screenHeightDp:999

screenWidthDp:768

screenLayout:4 (xlarge)

I don't have any idea why my app does not support this device on play store..
Do I miss something?

I really cannot figure out why this device filtered. :(

Edited) With

> aapt dump badging App.apk

then the log below shown.

```
sdkVersion:'18'
targetSdkVersion:'23'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.BLUETOOTH'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'
uses-permission: name='com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION'
uses-permission: name='android.permission.VIBRATE'


uses-feature: name='android.hardware.bluetooth'
uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.bluetooth' reason='requested android.permission.BLUETOOTH permission, requested android.permi
ssion.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permission, and targetSdkVersion > 4'
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location'
uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.location' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission, and request
ed android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission'
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location.gps'
uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.location.gps' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission'
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.location.network'
uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.location.network' reason='requested android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission'
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.landscape'
uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.screen.landscape' reason='one or more activities have specified a landscape orientation'
uses-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.touchscreen' reason='default feature for all apps'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'xlarge'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--' 'ca' 'da' 'fa' 'ja' 'pa' 'ta' 'nb' 'id' 'de' 'te' 'af' 'bg' 'th' 'fi' 'hi' 'vi' 'sk' 'uk' 'el' 'ml' 'nl' 'pl' 'sl' 'tl' 'am
' 'bn' 'in' 'kn' 'ko' 'ro' 'ar' 'fr' 'hr' 'mr' 'sr' 'tr' 'cs' 'es' 'ms' 'it' 'lt' 'pt' 'gu' 'hu' 'ru' 'zu' 'lv' 'sv' 'iw' 'sw' 'fr-CA' 'lo-L
A' 'en-GB' 'bn-BD' 'et-EE' 'ka-GE' 'ky-KG' 'km-KH' 'zh-HK' 'si-LK' 'mk-MK' 'ur-PK' 'hy-AM' 'my-MM' 'zh-CN' 'ta-IN' 'te-IN' 'ml-IN' 'en-IN' '
kn-IN' 'mr-IN' 'mn-MN' 'ne-NP' 'pt-BR' 'gl-ES' 'es-ES' 'eu-ES' 'is-IS' 'es-US' 'pt-PT' 'en-AU' 'zh-TW' 'ms-MY' 'kk-KZ' 'uz-UZ'
densities: '160' '213' '240' '320' '480' '640'
native-code: 'armeabi'
```